# How to add a string to a tree that has character values in each node

Tags: java, string, tree

So i want to make a tree of musical artists names and I want each node of the tree to be a character,
Here is my tree node class

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class TreeNode {

        char value;
        String songs;
        LinkedList<TreeNode> list; 
        public TreeNode(char ch, String st, LinkedList<TreeNode> node){
                value=ch;
                songs=st;
                list=node;
        } 
}
```

How would I make a method to add new names onto the tree.

Comment: This code is strange.  As the list is the container which is holding the TreeNode's then it should be external to this class

Answer (score 0):

This code is strange. As the list is the container which is holding the TreeNode's then it should be external to this class.

try

```
public class TreeNode {

  char value;
  String songs;
  public TreeNode(char ch, String st){
    value=ch;
    songs=st;
  } 
}

public class Main () {
    LinkedList<TreeNode> list = new LinkedList<TreeNode> ();
    TreeNode node = new TreeNode ('A', "Some String");
    TreeNode node2 = new TreeNode ('B', "Some Other String");
    list.add (node);
    list.add (node2);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare value as a String that will only be a single character long. That way you have a single alphabet value but it is a different datatype altogether.